# Добавление собственных правил на доступ к файлам в Windows через PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Добавил метки доступа к файлам и профилям пользователей Windows. Могу ли я каким нибудь образом добавить собственное условие в политику безопасности, чтобы при попытке доступа пользователя к файлу, данное условие проверяло совпадают ли данные метки и если да, то доступ разрешался и наоборот соответственно.

В какую сторону копать и что посмотреть по этому поводу?

Comment: А чем не устраивает встроенная система безопасности ОС?  Свойство разрешений на доступ есть почти у каждого объекта; есть система проверки подлинности; подсистема изменения, управления правами доступа и пр. Зачем перепроверять каждого пользователя, а затем присваивать нужные права? Полагаю, если возникла такая проблема - архитектура решения реализована в корне неверно. Если только Вы не разработчик собственной системы защиты информации :-)

Comment: Хочется реализовать мандатную модель разграничения доступа, которой в Windows нет

Comment: Полагаю тут верхнеуровневым решением - Powershell - не обойтись. Нужно как минимум писать драйверы, сервисы, оболочку управления... Если обойтись встроенными средствами, то, полагаю, всё что удастся реализовать: систему аудита (на базе аудита ОС). Благодаря который можно будет протоколировать доступ к объектам. Но на ходу управлять доступом - это вряд ли жизнеспособное решение.  Не найдете исходники продуктов Dallas Lock, Secret Net и т.п. Но может разработчики где-то выложили презентации архитектуры своих решений? Поищите эту информацию. Либо ищите её в статьях про исследование троянов :-)

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятно. Ну а если использовать встроенные системы, с их помощью можно сделать что-то наиболее похожее на мандатку или все что удастся это только аудит?

Comment: Теоретически можно, если абстрагироваться от реальной ОС. Но фактически, я полагаю, это будет виртуализация. А к реальным объектам операционной системы (процессы, файлы, реестр и т.д.) ограничивать доступ  средствами подсистем самой ОС - грубое и бесперспективное занятие - не надежно.